# MSVC. Отсутствуют библиотеки из папки experimental

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Мне нужен заголовочный файл <experimental/future>, но такого попросту нет, и #include ругается:
[image: Моя папка experimental]

Работаю в VS 2019 (16.11.2), в установщике выбирал средства сборки с "v142 ... (последняя версия)" в названии и также ещё "Модули C++ ... x64 или x86 - экспериментальная". Может, ещё надо что-то выбрать там?
Нужные мне функции даже в предварительную версию стандарта не включены, так что experimental/future должен быть. Я в замешательстве. В одной книге приводились примеры использования этой библиотеки, когда ещё C++20 не вышел.

P.S. А ещё должны быть, как минимум, experimental/latch, experimental/barrier, experimental/atomic...

Comment: Ваши знания слегка устаренли. Начиная с C++20, который поддерживает 19я студия, эти классы уже перестели быть экспериментальными (atomic, кстати, вошел в стандарт еще раньше)

Comment: @gbg, нет. Ни в c++20, ни в c++latest нет метода std::future<T>::then, который есть только в экспериментальной версии (стандартные версии не поддерживают т.н. продолжения). Следовательно, в стандарт они не входили

Comment: Не уверен, что VC++ поддерживает все экспериментальные возможности... если даже некоторые стандартные им не поддерживаются.